# Using a bench power supply to emulate car battery

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, dc, automotive

I am currently working on a project that involves a fuel lift pump.

I have been using a car battery to power the pump but am tired of having to charge the battery up over and over again. I  tried using a bench power supply but it went over its rated amperage.

Do you have any suggestions of a bench power supply to use for this project? I don't currently have the amperage I need handy (I know for a fact it is below 30A), but is there a place you would suggest starting?

Comment: You can buy some pretty big DC power supplies (100A+), depends on what you want to spend... You also need to take into account inrush current... This will probably be closed as a shopping question.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the battery with a trickle charger? Then you get the current you need and the battery stays topped up with a float charge when the pump isn’t running. The battery will last longer too, since by having a float change it won’t sulfate.

If you have space for a solar panel, you could use that (with a suitable controller) to keep the battery topped.

Answer (score 1):

If by emulating a car battery you mean simply being able to provide the needed voltage and amperage without any concern for the behavior of a large load on a lead acid battery like voltage droop, sagging, inductance/capacitance, recovery effect, powered/alternator vs unpowered, etc, then yes, you can use it. Your pump doesn't care about the voltage or current source.

Keep in mind that an active car system will be powered by the alternator and not the battery. Voltage will fluctuate based on the engine and is nominally 14.5V while the bare battery might be at 13V fully charged and down to 11V at the low usable end.

Any sufficiently sized 12 to 14V supply that meets the in rush current of your pump turning on, and ideally the stall current, will suffice. If you are into hobby projects then a average pc atx supply may have the current power you need, or a general purpose fixed supply if you pay enough. A variable bench supply would need to be pretty beefy but a fixed voltage supply can be found much easier.